# webpack devServer and proxy shows a 404 page

Tags: webpack, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

where am I supposed to connect when I proxy to an third domain like that ?

```
module.exports = {

  ...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        target: "http://www.example.org",
      },
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

shouldn't `localhost:8080` show `http://www.example.org` content ?

because I get a 404 page... (the same is true with other sites, I get not-founds, or even apache install pages!)

Comment: I tried to figure it out, but haven't been able to yet.  The following two links are documentation that should help solve the issue.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

and 

https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options

Comment: I think it could be a misconfiguration due to Mamp...

Comment: just tested on another computer and as suspected should be linked to some misconfiguration on my laptop. besides, don't really know where to start to figure it out, uninstalling MAMP didn't help...

Comment: I know this post is old, but have you found a solution?

Comment: the solution in my own answer worked well for me

Answer (score 2):

this is the right configuration

```
module.exports = {
...
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "/": {
      target: "http://www.example.org",
      changeOrigin: true
    },
  }
}
...
}
```